# How can DataGridComboBoxColumn style be changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I need to change border style to invisible on "DataGridComboBoxColumn"...
How can I do it? I hope there is another way then changing to datagridTemplate and put combobox element with my style inside....

Comment: You can set the border to null by using BorderBrush={x:null}, although this will remove the 1px border that surrounds your element and may change the visual layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add .EditingElementStyle

```
<wpfToolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgcSource" Header="Source"
      SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ObjectItemSourceId, TargetNullValue=0}" 
      SelectedValuePath="ID"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      SortMemberPath="SourceName">
    <wpfToolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </wpfToolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</wpfToolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a5777acb-ef85-40e3-b371-d803cbe26763/